# Get jsp current page

Tags: html, jsp, url, servlets

I have a footer with a few links that open in the same tab, but I want to have them open in a new tab whenever the user is on the payment page.
I have decided to do it with using `boolean` condition that becomes true whenever the user is on `/payment.jsp`. What I am not sure about is how to get the current page?

```
<% boolean paymentPage = false; %>

<% if(paymentPage ){ %>
        <new tab>
<% } else{ %>
        <same tab>
<% } %>
```

It seems to me that the best way to do so is to use the `HttpServletRequest` interface. I was hoping I could get an advice on how to implement it in my code. I assume it would look something like this?

```
<% private boolean paymentPageTest (HttpServletRequest request) { %>
<%  return request.getRequestURL.equals("/Payment.jsp"); %>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your assumption(Logic) the function paymentPageTest needs to be declared in **JSP declaration tag** as below:

```
<%! 
 private boolean paymentPageTest (HttpServletRequest request){
    return request.getRequestURL.equals("/Payment.jsp"); 
 } 
 %>
```

Use the below logic to check whether the page is `/Payment.jsp`

```
<%! 
    private boolean paymentPageTest(HttpServletRequest request){

     String path = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI();
     if (path.endsWith("/Payment.jsp")) {
         return true;//new tab
     }else{
         return false;//current tab
     }
    }
%>
```

Comment: Yes, that does look cleaner. Unfortunately it doesn't work though.

Comment: ok, The logic needs to be updated. Will try to build it. Where have you written the first code(the code in first code block)? which jsp/file? I needs its filename.

Answer (score 0):

In a JSP file:

```
request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri")
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
<% boolean paymentPage = false; %>

<% String str = request.getRequestURL().toString(); %>
<% if(str == "<url>") {paymentPage = true;} %>

<% if(paymentPage ){ %>
        <new tab>
<% } else{ %>
        <same tab>
<% } %>
```